# i'm trying to display my out onto a new file on python then take the total of that file and print it?

Tags: python

I've tried:

```
f = open("sample_file.txt", "r")
for line in f.readlines():
   line = line.strip()
   line_flt = float(line)
   num=line_flt/3-2
   pay = int(num)
   f= open("the_answers","w+")
   f.writelines(pay)
   print(pay)
```

Comment: Outstanding move

Comment: Don't name your second file with f, but choose an other name and it should work. You can also move the open outside the loop it will avoid the program to open it every time

Comment: Reusing f is not the issue here

Comment: Please add more details. What's the output now? and what you expect it to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to write an `int` to the file and the method does not accept that.

```
# try changing this line to:
# pay = str(num)
# to this:
pay = str(num)
# keep the rest of the code as it is.
```

Also, do not open the file in the loop, you can simply store the values you want to write in a string and write them at once. Something like this:

```
f = open("sample_file.txt", "r")
pay = ""
for line in f.readlines():
    line = line.strip()
    line_flt = float(line)
    num = line_flt / 3 - 2
    pay += str(num) + "\n"

f = open("the_answers","w+")
f.writelines(pay)
```

Hope this helps. Good luck.